# Undefined index with (is_numeric($POST[

Tags: php

I am using a php form which will get the cid from the URL. e.g records.php?cid=23

But I am getting the error Undefined index of cid in the following line.

> if (is_numeric($_POST['cid']))

```
 if (isset($_GET['cid']))
    {
    // if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    // make sure the 'cid' in the URL is valid
    if (is_numeric($_POST['cid']))
    {
    // get variables from the URL/form
    $cid = $_POST['cid'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `GET` not `POST`. `$_GET['cid']`